# is it possible to use methods "get" and "post" in one form

Tags: html

I am using both radio buttons and a field where people can enter their username, is it possible to do both method = post + method = get?

I have got the example code down below;

```
<form name='login' method='post' method='get' action='?page=purchase'>
  <input type="text" name="username"> <br />
  <input type="radio" name="option_1" value="option_1">
  <input type='submit' title='Submit'>
</form>
```

Comment: What would you expect the result to be like?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. You want to perform two separate requests, at the same time, with the same data, to the same server, but using different methods? ......why?

Comment: You can do method=post with `<input type="hidden" name="page" value="purchase">`.

Answer (score 4):

No, but you can make a POST request with a query string in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

No you cant have both methods.